Is this (highly upvoted) question acceptable or does it "Need more focus"?
Image Processing: Algorithm Improvement for 'Coca-Cola Can' Recognition (with almost 2000 upvotes) seems to be a bit disputed (timeline) over the last week or so:

Six community members have voted-to-close it (three users each, twice now)
Then two separate moderators have reopened it

If we go further back in the timeline, there have been two other closures:

One time reopened by Shog9 (after migration to dsp.stackexchange.com was rejected)
Another time reopened by community vote.

Given the confusion with this question over the years, chat consensus is that discussion here might be helpful so that it is clear to the Community (and/or perhaps Mods) why it should or shouldn't remain open.
From my perspective, it's a well-written and clearly interesting question, but if you scroll down to the bottom, the problem to me is that it is four, separate, unrelated questions.
(Summarized)

How can I improve the significant performance issues?
How can I improve detection of cans when there are bottles in the image?
How can I improve detection in fuzzy images?
How can I improve detection of cans that are not directly facing the camera?

It seems to me (and others) that this question "Needs more focus - This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.".
Each of the four questions in here are perfectly good questions on their own, but shouldn't they have been separate questions and not lumped into one?
No one is suggesting deleting the question or the answers - It's an interesting read, but does it really need to be open to new answers given the root issues?
Or, if we're missing something, what is it?  What is the rationale that the Mods have for it being reopened?
Again, I think it would just be useful to get this cleared up "once and for all" since it's now gone back and forth 4 times over the years (twice in the last week).

Tsyvarev's answer from "Should two-part questions be closed?" might be relevant here. It depends on if you see these "individual questions" as individual parts of the overall "How do I improve/fix this specific detection algorithm?" question or not. I'd say they are, since if just "how do I improve the algorithm" was asked, those four individual steps would be in the singular answer regardless.

@ipodtouch0218 "how do I improve the algorithm" seems like a very broad and unfocused question, especially in the absence of any code used to implement the original algorithm. Answers would either be more opinionated pontification or hundreds/thousands of lines of code (and the answerers have all chosen the former.)

Do we generally retroactively close old questions from many years ago? It seems like some iffy questions from 2010-2016 are allowed to persist but if they were asked today we'd probably hold them to higher standards. (and that doesn't seem like a huge issue--or at least, trying to sort through all grandfathered in questions seems herculean)

@Kaia we do, yea, rarely

@miken32 "how do I improve X" without any other context is 100% unclear. In this post, however, the when OP thoroughly explained: the end goal, gave examples, listed requirements and restrictions, listed the image preprocessing steps, gave the exact algorithm chosen (and why), how they interpret the output of the algorithm, listed the results, gave their observations on those results, and what they want improved... I'd say that the post is anything but unclear.

@ipodtouch0218 It's definitely not unclear what they want, and it's clearly a well-researched question, but IMO it's asking too much for a single question.

@miken32 Is it on topic to ask for guidelines to solve a bigger problem? says questions like these are fine as long as they have enough detail to be answered, which this definitely does.

A big part of closing questions is speculation—trying to predict that the answers will likely be low-quality based on well-established heuristics about the way the question is asked. For historical questions, you don't have to engage in unbounded speculation or look at heuristics, because you can simply look at the existing answers. Is it causing a problem? Is it low-quality? If not, then you can (and should be) a lot less strict in whether you seek to and how you apply the guidelines for closing a question. Don't close things that don't need to be closed, even if they're an anomaly.

It looks like a kickstarter campaign! In 2012 they really did write them questions differently. With modern standards in mind I find it hard to not be influenced by the fact that it opens like a blog post and reads more like a programming challenge rather than an actual programming problem, it's definitely written to attract close votes. But if people want this to be open so people can now suggest AI tooling to do the work... meh. It kind of looks like this is being closed because it comes dangerously close to being "fun" which is of course, highly illegal.

@CodyGray A couple of points on that - (1) Most importantly, it's not just "low-quality" answers that are a problem. In this case, having 4 separate questions in one means that most of the answers are addressing different problems. Some focus only on performance, some only on the bottle-problem, some on orientation, and none on fuzziness. A few cover two or even three topics, but separately.  The third-most upvoted, for instance, covers bottle-masking but doubles-processing time, so runs counter to one of the goals.

(2) I won't call the accepted answer "link-only", but it's close -- Maybe 1% of the necessary info is in the answer, and the other 99% behind the links. Two of the three links to the papers are dead, but at least the Wikipedia links are still there. And the fact that it links to multiple lengthy topics comes pretty close to (if not over the line of) the "if you can imagine writing a book" rule. If the comments are correct, it also doesn't address the bottle-problem.

(3) With one-third of the answers being deleted, I'm not sure that we can say that it hasn't attracted its fair share of low-quality answers over the years, can we? Even for the undeleted, consider this, this, and this that are closer to being comments or discussions than than answers (albeit well-written and upvoted). As mentioned in the comments under it, even the accepted answer practically just boils down to being a comment that says, "try using SIFT".

@NotTheDr01ds links are updated now. Also we wouldn't consider such answers link only because it does have a substance beyond mere links.

@DalijaPrasnikar Agreed - Note that I said that I wouldn't call it link-only, but when the vast majority of an answer is behind the links, that's not a great sign.  Books (at least papers) have been written in this case ;-)

If this question was asked today by a low rep user, would it be closed?

I've locked the post for 7 days while things are being resolved here. The number of closes and reopens in a short period of time is becoming disruptive. I'll be happy to unlock the post should a resolution be reached before the 7-day timer expires.

Thanks @HenryEcker - I should have foreseen this and revoked my close-vote while it was being discussed here anyway.  Not sure that it would have mattered, but yeah - given the back-and-forth I strongly agree :-)

@JonSG I know my next comment is going to sound snide, but (all readers) please understand that's not the intention. I think the problem is that this would be closed even after 10 years if it (and the answers) weren't so highly upvoted, but I think that's a red-herring.  Many of the highly-upvoted answers aren't even great.  There are 28 upvotes (and only two downvotes) on an answer from someone who admits to having absolutely no expertise and just finds it an interesting topic so wanted to throw out some ideas.

@NotTheDr01ds, I've solved people's problems many times without having ever used the language or library in question myself. And in general, it is not that unusual for a new viewpoint from a non-expert to help things along. Honestly, I'd be much more worried about the people that do claim to be experts in everything...

Posting this question as-is wouldn’t fly today. It would be quickly closed with “seeking recommendations” cited as the reason. It doesn’t include a proper minimal reproducible example. It doesn’t even include unprocessed images so others can try OP’s original data and, you know, reproduce and "enhance" their algorithm, as they request. Maybe it was relevant 12 years ago, when OpenCV wasn't that well documented, but today I don’t think it is; much of the recommendations given in the answers section can be found googling the state of the art for this particular problem.

@stateMachine Other possible issues aside, the "Seeking recommendations" close reason clearly does not apply. The question is quite explicitly clear, in boldface text, that it wants an answer "using exclusively OpenCV features", as opposed to, say, recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources.

@RyanM I was thinking more along the lines of recommendations to improve the algorithm, which seems what the OOP asked for.

@stateMachine that's not what that close reason refers to, though.  It's not just "Seeking recommendations"; it's "Seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources".  You need to consider the entire text of the close reason, not just the first two words.

@AleksiTorhamo That's completely fair, but in this case the answer just sounded to me too much like what you see on a "Forum/Discussion Board". I just feel like too many of the answers have "upvotes by association" - It's an interesting, fun question (that I still think should be closed, despite its popularity) that has attracted a number of answers that, as long as they also look interesting and well-written, were often upvoted by association (again, it seems to me).

@DalijaPrasnikar I also think an answer from you or Cody to explain your thoughts would be a great addition to this post. I have read your comments, and appreciate you responding in time, but answers are more visible, hence, better. Cheers.

I am a bit busy at the moment and writing comments is easier than writing elaborate answer that can stand on Meta.

@M-- My patience for writing lengthy, reasoned answers on Meta fighting with deletionists who want to myopically interpret rules at the expense of valuable content wore thin many years ago. I'll continue to use my moderator powers to rescue things that I think need to be rescued and enforce what needs to be enforced, and I'm happy to write comments both in service of constructive discussions and to give additional insights to those who want to take the time to write comprehensive answers (like kjhughes has done and I have upvoted), but I just don't see the value in putting more time into it.

@CodyGray Can you point us to a canonical Meta post then that would explain this Mod policy?  I just couldn't find one. I'd be happy to close this as a duplicate of it in that case. Thanks!

@CodyGray I understand. Although I am shocked to read that you are calling this a fight with deletionists. I for one, and am sure many others, are talking about closing. And I know you have closed other "highly upvoted" questions, that one would find useful (I can go find one, but that's not evidence of anything, each question is obviously different). The answer you upvoted also is offering wrong insight (or at least different ones than the ones I understood during my tenure). I probably need to read more and better understand closing and its effects (I mean it, genuinely).

@M--SavetheDataDump Do not close something you are not fine with being deleted. (with the exception of sign post duplicates) Closing is just a first step towards deletion. It does not have to happen, but it also can. If you vote to close something you want to be preserved, you are opening deletion path to others that may not share the same POV.

@DalijaPrasnikar and then I can vote to undelete. With that reasoning, we shouldn't be voting to close questions which can be improved to be on-topic either. Let's put aside the point about deleting or not deleting for a second, and disregard the score. Would you make the case for this question and justify it being on topic? Couple of other users and I did list our reasons for closing, but I haven't read any clear responses debunking those (I responded to the first 2 answers and invalidated their arguments). P.S. e.g. see this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6461462/m-save-the-data-dump

@M--SavetheDataDump that you invalidated someone's arguments is your opinion. I am not going to make the case, because it would be exercise in futility. People have already made up their minds, and there is very little I can say that was not already said in answers arguing for reopening or comments.

@DalijaPrasnikar no, that's not a matter of opinion. I made counterarguments. If one believes they're not valid, they should provide reasons why. Until then, those are invalidated. I am not sure about other people, but I haven't made up my mind. I am not sure I'd even VTC on that question again, and honestly I don't care about one specific question. I am interested in the larger picture. Anyway, it seems you are not keen to spend time on this (I don't blame you, you have more important things), and our discussion hasn't borne any fruit in a while. I'll stop here.

@M--SavetheDataDump If you are interested in larger picture, then when there is doubt the best action is the one that does the least harm, meaning leaving the question open. We are discussing here around nuances of whether the question asks too many questions in one or whether it is not clear or specific enough about goals and similar where many of reasoning is bound to be more or less a matter of opinion. This is the best signal that it should be left open.

@DalijaPrasnikar I never argued about number of questions. Let's say I don't see it that way. I leave it there. Cheers. P.S. I may ask a question about the larger picture, if I found the time (maybe being on vacation gave me too much time to discuss nuisances).

Closure is absolutely not just a "first step to deletion". Otherwise every question that is closed would auto-Roomba at some point. Given that there are myriad rules that exempt closed questions from deletion (not just for duplicate closures), it's quite difficult to see validity in that position. I'm likewise confused why deletion was ever mentioned in comments; it's totally irrelevant here and any mention of it is a red herring.

The more I look at the question the more problems I find with it. Did the OP really not include the actual implementation of their algorithm that they want help improving? Because it looks like that's the case. I can maybe understand not including the data depending on what format it's in, but not even including the algorithm itself is clear, objective "No MCVE" territory.

Oh geez, I'm just stumbling upon this post now, after casting a close vote via the close queue. I really don't see any logic in leaving that post open, but apparently that's a contentious position. FWIW, I think most, but not all, closed questions deserve to be deleted. This question is one that I wouldn't vote to delete.

NotTheDr01ds provides a great summary and legit arguments in favor of closing the question. However, the other answers (and comments) put forward claims that are either categorically wrong or fail to capture the whole picture.


Applying closure rules to long-ago asked questions despite clear evidence of the value of a question and its attracted answers does the opposite: ...

We often receive comments underneath a closed post or questions on Meta about a closed question comparing their post to an older one similar to theirs that is not closed, is upvoted, and is generally well-received. The short answer to those questions/comments is that something that was once on-topic, may not be anymore; and because something fell into cracks, it doesn't mean their posts should get a pass. We also usually proceed to close the older post (there's a chatroom dedicated to closing older questions).
Also see historical-lock and read its tag wiki, specifically the community wiki post on MSE. The main reason for historical locks is to deal with questions such as the one in question (although that usually gets applied to valuable questions on the path of deletion). If closing such questions (not letting new answers to be posted) was not the right decision ever (as the other answer on this post argues), then historical locks shouldn't have "frozen" the posts. But closing doesn't mean deleting. If the older post does not offer any value, we may also cast delete votes. And if there are disputes about that, moderators may apply a historical lock.
Posts that are not deleted, still live on the site, and any new contributor can post a new, but on-topic, question/answer pair to provide the community with what they consider useful.
Bottom line is that keeping off-topic questions open has nothing to do with cherishing previous contributions. Not deleting them (with or without a historical lock) is how we cherish them.

The other answer here focuses on the count of questions. While I agree with Cody's comment regarding whether asking the questions separately would improve the quality or not, which I don't think it would in this case, I personally did not vote to close the question because it asked too many questions, rather because it was asking "how to improve" the algorithm (whether asking for improvements on their existing approaches or asking for other better ones) without providing enough details to provide a well-defined framework on how to measure improvements. As Stephen's comment mentioned, that led to 42 answers with varying quality and different outlooks. That's why I consider the question to be broad, opinion-based, and even somewhat unclear (I don't think asking for an MCVE (specifically asking for code) is necessary for this question).

I am sorry, but like I said for you other comment. Closed means eligible for deletion. In other words it is as good as deleted, but community haven't get around to deleting it yet. There are million of other questions worth closing and I don't understand the desire to nuke this one. When you say it shouldn't be deleted, that means that you do think there is some value there. When there is a doubt we should do no harm, we should leave the post open, especially ones that have proven their usefulness through votes.

This is not a good choice for historical lock which should be used sparsely and mostly to prevent deletion of undoubtfully off-topic questions.

@Dalija I disagree with your definition of closed (i.e. eligible for deletion). Take SOCVR; we close a lot of questions, but not deleting every single one of them. I think if we could reach to a common ground regarding that, we could further this discussion effectively. It is very late here, but I am interested to talk more about this if you had the time. And just to clarify, I don't want to nuke this question. Like many other questions, I happened to come across it and now like other specific questions on meta, I am interested in knowing more (and establishing a standard) for future cases. GN

"Closed means eligible for deletion." No, not at all. Closed means does not fulfill the current quality standard for questions, nothing more. There are more specific versions of closed (Off-topic, opinion based, …) that add further meaning, but just closed in general doesn't. "In other words it is as good as deleted, but community haven't get around to deleting it yet." if that were truly the case then surely we should just let roomba delete every closed question after some time threshold. We don't because closed does have more nuances than simply "should be deleted".

@DalijaPrasnikar or are you actually advocating for deletion of every one of the over a million closed questions that are not deleted?

A historical lock means that the community cannot maintain the question at all. Nor can they give any feedback on it. Why is that better? How would that improve anything over leaving it open? A historical lock is the last refuge of a moderator who wants to preserve content that we feel might be useful or otherwise of interest to future viewers when we have exhausted all other powers of persuasion and are otherwise fighting a community of voters intent on deleting the Q&A altogether. Are we at that point now? Again? For yet another old, valuable, dare I say epic Q&A?

@cafce25 no. I am not advocating for deleting them all, although if most of those were deleted we wouldn't lost much of value and it would probably be easier to find good answers for people searching for solutions. My point is that all those can be deleted by community and they often are. Even moderators will delete some of those if the stumble upon them while doing some other mod work. Ideally questions should be open, being signpost duplicates (good duplicates) or should not exist. Everything that does not fit in the above is just sitting in the limbo because we cannot moderate all.

Why don't we run scripts... because there might be some value in some of those closed questions, but we cannot evaluate or improve them all to have them reopened.  Eventually, it all falls down to scale and our collective moderation abilities.

@DalijaPrasnikar There thousands gems among the closed, non duplicate questions, that cannot be made into good questions according to current question standards, I can't support reopening them because they set a bad precedent, I can't support deleting them because, well they are gems. That in my opinion only leaves us the option of closed, which cannot mean the same as "to be deleted or improved" because again, those are gems to which neither is applicable to. What do you suppose we do with them as your interpretation of closed doesn't apply to them?

@cafce25 If there are gems among those closed, and as far as topicality is concerned they are programming related, but just don't follow some other more nuanced guidelines, then I would be more in favor revisiting those and seeing how they can be reopened, especially if they can potentially receive additional good answers than keeping them closed. But that is another discussion. If we close this one on "technicality" then it would just join those other gems that were closed and maybe they shouldn't be.

Great, but not all of these are redeemable, not without invalidating answers, what do we do with these? And what do we do with those that aren't programming related. I don't see a way (without creating a new status "no longer suitable" or is that just a historic lock which also according to you should be used sparingly) where closed "is as good as deleted"

I guess I just fundamentally disagree that closed "is as good as deleted", that might work for new questions, but I don't think it can work across the board, not with the historical development of [so].

@CodyGray I think the dispute here is between community and some of the moderator :) It seems that community leans toward closing the question but not deleting it. While you and Dalija and probably some other want this open (some of the mods agree with closure). Historical lock is to end the reopen/close war, but now with a clearer head morning, I think we can rely on mods to play by the rule and follow the consensus. I will edit that part.

@DalijaPrasnikar Re: "I don't understand the desire to nuke this one" - I think the desire is to understand why this one shouldn't be closed (not deleted) when many others have been. There honestly seems to be no logical reason other than "the community thinks there's value by upvoting it and the answers", but see my next comment for an example of a highly upvoted question (with highly upvoted answer) that has been (and should be) closed.

Also, keep in mind that it requires 10 delete votes to remove something that is this highly upvoted, and it's usually many years before that happens.  Take this very off-topic, very outdated question that was closed 5 years ago and still only has 4 of the 10 needed delete votes. I just wouldn't be all that concerned about closing it making it "eligible for deletion" honestly.

@NotTheDr01ds The difference between those two question sis that former is on topic as it is programming related (improving algorithm) while the later is not. So even if the latter question has value it unfortunately sits on the wrong site. So merely having value or being upvoted is not the (only) deciding factor.

@DalijaPrasnikar we can find examples of closed and not closed questions regarding improving an algorithm. Take this question from Cody which I even awarded a bounty on it. That is a good, well-scoped, and on-topic question. The one we are discussing now, is not necessarily bad, but I still believe is broad.

@M--SavetheDataDump Not all questions are equally good or bad. It is a spectrum, we have to draw line at some point. I think that this one we are discussing here belongs on the open side of that line and it is not that it just barely satisfies it.

@Dalija I am sorry, but I don't think making statements without reasoning is the right path for reaching consensus. You saying "it belongs on the open side", without offering proper arguments, cannot be anything more than your opinion; and cannot be regarded as a guideline. Obviously each question falls somewhere on the spectrum, and as I said we can find examples of good or great, bad or terrible questions. P.S. Inductive reasoning does not work here (I brought up Cody's question just to tell you that simply asking about algorithm is not enough to make a question on topic.

@DalijaPrasnikar Both questions have issue, of differing degrees, sure. The other question is a convenient comparison because it (a) shows that "especially ones that have proven their usefulness through votes" isn't a good litmus test, and (b) it goes to your point that "In other words it is as good as deleted, but community haven't get around to deleting it yet." That is clearly just nowhere near the case, as shown by that incredibly off-topic, outdated question that I think we can all agree doesn't belong here still remaining 5 years after being closed.

@NotTheDr01ds I was talking about votes in context of questions that are related to programming, thus on topic, but may be closed for some other more nuanced reason. Votes do matter on such questions. The other WSL question is not deleted because it requires plenty of delete votes and just because it is still here that does not mean that it will not get deleted eventually. I also cast a delete vote on that question before I became a mod. There are plenty of other questions that were deleted and being closed is just s first step in that direction.

@M-- "I think the dispute here is between community and some of the moderator". I don't believe that's true. To begin, the highest-scoring answer is disagreeing with closure. Furthermore, there are a small number of people discussing this in the comments, including yourself, NotTheDr01ds, and two mods. That seems pretty balanced on community vs. mods to me. I would also argue that the Meta participants are not necessarily representative of the community at large. This can be both good and bad. Mods sometimes have a unique perspective. I still oppose a historical lock for practical reasons.

@CodyGray you are right. I portrayed the dispute inaccurately. The score has changed since your comment, but that could change again. I believe we have had good discussions in SOCVR and here. Do you think posting a general question (maybe a CW) is warranted to document them?

To dispel some confusion, here is the MSE FAQ on when a historical lock should be used: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for/126631#126631

@DalijaPrasnikar "In other words it is as good as deleted, but community haven't get around to deleting it yet." This is simply not true. We don't delete every question that is closed here, and it's disingenuous to suggest that that's the case. Not every unlocked question that is closed gets auto-deleted, and 10k+ users aren't going around deleting everything the Community user doesn't auto-delete, either. Let's not conflate "a lot of closed questions get deleted" with "everything that gets closed gets deleted".

@TylerH "We don't delete every question that is closed here," No we don't do that, but we do actually delete a lot highly visited and upvoted ones. I am also coming from the deletionist camp Cody mentioned, so I am not saying that out of nowhere. The point is that once the question is closed there is no guarantee it will not get deleted. It is not that we are deleting from worst to the best closed questions and there will be a long list before question like this one will start getting delete votes. We are deleting them randomly as they come by.

@DalijaPrasnikar Luckily there is a way to guarantee a post won't get deleted after it's closed, if it's worth keeping around but at risk of deletion: a historical lock. As for the order, that's a red herring. No one's talking about deleting bad stuff before less bad stuff, and the random order of deletion is not really a problem on the site, anyway.

@TylerH Historical lock is a really bad option for any question. For blatantly off-topic ones it may be sufficiently fine to use it, as it is less of two evils. But using such lock on questions where there is already a dispute about topicality is very far from ideal scenario.

@DalijaPrasnikar what would an ideal scenario look like?

@KevinB Leaving the question open. If there is a dispute, then leaving the question open is less harmful. If you are talking about historical locks, they are bad because they prevent any interactions and maintenance of the content. But if you are asking me about better solution in terms of locking, I haven't through much about that as there are many possible usage scenarios and possible implementations.

Leave it open, so that it can continue to be closed/reopened? or... The whole reason we're here is because that wasn't working.

One point to know if a question is good is to check the answers.
Answer 1: It's recommending 2 algorithms, and explain why they can answer. But, the answer itself say this has issue, and a comment explain why it think it should not be accepted (comment highly upvoted too). So, this answer doesn't seems "so good".
Answer 2: Give great ideas, which has issue too. Doesn't give any link or code. It also could be with "I would be surprised if this weren't [...]" opinion. Again, a comment explain the main issue of this answer. So, this answer too doesn't seems really good.
Answer 3: 1/3 of personal informations (anecdote), 1/3 for a question, 1/3 of "my question should be easy to answer". Clearly a bad answer to me.
Answer 4: Proposition another product than OpenCV, which is off-topic to the question. Or, if we consider as on-topic, it means the question is well looking for recommendation, which is a closure reason for Stack Overflow.
Answer 5: Proposing another product. It also proposes code in other languages. Which is off-topic of the question.
Answer 6: Finally a good answer! I mean, a fine one. it's refering to other answers and proposing new way, with multiple links to learn more/help to do it.
Answer 7: Another fine answer. Less explaination but gives link to directly start the subject.
Answer 8: Not bad, but can be improved. Most of the post is using Xbox Kinect's content, but the link is not useful. It's laking reference, link, or code.
Answer 9: "There is a lot of ways, I'm using one of them" but which one? what are those ways? Even if it's explained in the paper, it would be useless if the link broke. This answer should include more details.
I'll not do it for all the 23 undeleted answers, but as you can see, they are not all good, but why?

To me, there is one very important issue: "Can you help me improve my specific algorithm" but it doesn't give code. So, people can't help without code. If a post appear now, it would be downvoted and closed for needs debugging details.
It's easy to involve your opinion in this type of posts, which is off-topic for SO.

I know there is good content in it.

The question itself explains everything, with examples and results.
Answers are not duplicates of each other.
Answers propose ways or products that can be useful.

Conclusion
Even if this question has good aspect, it also has negative ones. I think this can be splitted into sub questions or even linked with topics asked on Data science. I think this tries to ask a lot of questions (as "How to recognize image?, here is how I do but it doesn't works properly., etc.") because it's a large project.
It received a lot of upvotes because a lot of people start with this. But if the question has 3 times more upvote than most-upvoted answer, it seems people doesn't all find their answer. In general, it's the opposite (that's why there is a popup as "you didn't vote on a question since long time") (example and I just take most upvoted on c++).
I would vote to close this post (in benefic to others according to the same subject). The argument "the post is old" is not a valid one.

Applying closure rules to newly asked questions generally improves the quality of the site.
Applying closure rules to long-ago asked questions despite clear evidence of the value of a question and its attracted answers does the opposite:

It cuts off potential contributors inspired by the challenge of the question and the quality of the existing answers.

It sends a signal that anal-retentive rule-following is more important than the clear value an outlier Q/A provides to the community at large.


But it'll encourage more bad questions!
No, it won't.  The overwhelmingly dominant reason for bad questions is laziness on the part of the asker and has nothing to do with even an awareness of the rules, let alone any conscious plan to work around them.
But consistency!
Sure, be consistent up-front, but if somehow some Q/A slips through and becomes a gem, don't close or delete it — cherish it!

"despite clear evidence of the value of a question and its attracted answers" - The problem here is that, no matter how upvoted, the answers here demonstrate the problem with the question itself - Each answer addresses a different question, so there could be 4 "best" answers for each of the issues (with performance being a "constraint" for the other three as well as an "issue" in itself).

@NotTheDr01ds: Precision is less important than value, and the voting on the question and answers clearly signals that value has been provided.

You had mentioned this concern elsewhere, too, @Not. I don't understand why it's a problem that different answers engage with different aspects. Answers to any question could just as well present different solutions that are better under different circumstances, thus resulting in multiple "best" answers. This is, incidentally, why there is no such thing as a "best" answer, and why you can upvote as many or as few answers as you want. The ideal condition is not necessarily that there is only 1 single answer to every question.

@CodyGray It's been brought up before, but perhaps the close reason is incorrectly worded then, because the reason itself clearly points to multiple questions in one being a problem.  While a single question can have many different solutions, isn't the problem that multiple questions in one can never (rarely) have just one solution? Again, the problem here is that the answers are all over the board - Having this as separate questions would have allowed each topic to be addressed with good answers for that question, but that's not what we're getting here.

Put differently, you can't possibly accept four answers to each of the four separate questions.

Yeah we can consistently leave old stuff be, unless it is really damaging in some way like a wrong answer. This isn't, it's just an annoyance to people who live inside the rulebook.

They were “consistent up front.” It was closed the day after it was asked. A mod opened it up again without explanation

@miken32: And being consistent up-front is good. Yet somehow the gem-to-be slipped through, and the point now is that it deserves to live the life it's earned, not be snuffed out because rules.

There are 19 deleted answers on this question. Leaving it open means that there may be a significant number of new answers that will need moderation.  I'm not sure that allowing new answers is worth the amount of work to keep up with them.  Closing (but not deleting) old topics like that has practical benefits.

@StephenOstermiller: That argument is valid but not universally applicable.  (In this case, most of those 19 were good faith efforts to contribute, and there are 34 answers that have passed moderation standards -- this is not an intrinsically bad-answer attracting question such as those that solicit opinions.)   I prefer to espouse general principles, and my point here is that Q/A that has proven to provide value should not be deleted or closed merely because rules.

The question hasnt' attracted a good answer in nearly 12 years, i don't think we need to worry about closure preventing future answers. It's likely any future answer would be effectively... throw out everything you've done/thought about and do it this other way... which isn't necessarily the best outcome here given it wouldn't really be answering any of the given questions. Closure would cause no harm here, assuming it was for a valid reason.

@StephenOstermiller There are many questions that have many answers. We are not closing questions just because they might attract new answers. This is not "Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?" kind of question where there is not much new that can be said on the topic. Algorithms can be improved. We cannot assume that there won't be any more worthwhile answers to that question.

@DalijaPrasnikar it's not about whether new/better algorithms are possible or not. It's about whether that question establishes a clear standard on how to measure improvements. If you can edit it to clarify that (I cannot, believe me I've tried, but that doesn't prove it's impossible), then I am all for keeping it open. Otherwise, keeping it closed but not deleting it is the best course of action, IMHO.

@M--SavetheDataDump I think the question elaborates rather good what are considered as improvements. Additionally, that Q/A is no longer just for the OP, but it has been proven useful for others and interpretations of what is appropriate improvement will vary. Not everyone will be detecting cans. We don't have to nitpick here. If the question is closed (dead) that means it is eligible for deletion. Exception is for sign post duplicates. This is not such question, if you say that it shouldn't be deleted then it should stay open as improving algorithms is on topic for SO.

@DalijaPrasnikar I proposed a historical lock.

@M--SavetheDataDump doesn't historical lock is kind of closing for adding new answers but not deleting the question?

@ArtemSychov no, it's more than that. Closing itself has that effect. Historical lock is for when there are disputes. Tagi wiki for [meta-tag:historical-lock] has more info and useful link(s).

"But it'll encourage more bad questions! No, it won't." It has and it will, just perhaps not to an unacceptably large extent as you argued. I have seen quite a few users following the format of some old question and explicitly said they did so. It's a tradeoff, and as with all tradeoffs, please don't be dismissive towards one side.

@PasserBy: I stand by that statement in the context I provided but you elided.

@StephenOstermiller You've just described the exact use-case and value of the historical lock :-) Questions that were once considered acceptable that today are not (like this one), and that continue to receive bad answers (like this one), and that continuously get closed and reopened (like this one), and that are popular--e.g. have high view counts and scores (like this one) generally get historically locked. That preserves the content that's good, sends a clear signal to readers that rules are different now compared to when it was asked, and prevents new bad content from being added.

So after some time I'm counting



question
sentiment
votes for closing
votes for leaving it open




M--s answer
in favor of closing
+13
-8


Elikill58s answer
in favor of closing
+13
-8


kjhughes answer
in favor of leaving open
-21
+25


ipodtouch0218s answer
in favor of leaving open
-19
+16










66 votes that line up with closing
57 votes that line up with leaving open



In addition we have
22 votes to close + 5 votes to migrate the question to another site
opposed to 3 moderators and 6 users that voted to reopen.
It seems quite tight but still pretty clear the community is in favor of closing the question, yet some moderators seem entitled to keep it open because it attracted some attention and thus some votes.
I had hoped elected moderators knew better than to repeatedly go against the community majority in favor of closing this question.

"but still pretty clear the community is in favor of closing the question" sounds like a statement from a populist candidate just like before presidential elections... // Nb's in the Answer: 56 for closing and 49 for keeping open. => As just one single User, I'm able to DV the 2 Answers in favor of closing and UV the 2 Answers for keeping open, and now 56 <> 49 becomes 54 <> 51. // If as just one single User I can influence the Delta from 7 to 3, do you really think it's "still pretty clear"...? Just one more User voting like me and the result gets reversed to 52 <> 53.

Yes, 25 votes to close/migrate vs 9 users vote to reopen on the question itself, that's pretty clear.

Yeah, but you cannot really compare the 'Close Votes' with the 'Reopen Votes' because the 'Reopen Votes' (and the Mods) only come "in (re)action" when (after) there have already been 3 'Close Votes' from 3 loose individuals... (And there is no "Anti-migrate" Vote, so you can't draw any conclusion on the 'Migrate Votes') So, no, I don't find the Stats "clear" (in favor of Closing)...

Well it's clear over time the community has repeatedly found that question close worthy oror not belonging here.

@chivracq at the very least it's not a clear enough "in favor of open" that the mods should repeatedly enforce that state IMO.

If there is no consensus what should happen to the post, why do the mods enforce one side, "hey don't need to "wait" for another 2 Users casting again and again 2 Reopen Votes to reopen the Question." why not do the same for close votes?

"Why do Mods do [x]...?", well, I don't know, ask them...! But I think Cody Gray (Mod) gave the "rationale" they use in that Comment.

I would say that it's focused enough, and that the moderators were correct in their decision to reopen the question.
If you think that it isn't focused because it contains multiple questions in one:
From Should two-part questions be closed?:

Several questions in a post are allowed if they are closely related. That is, if one question in many cases implies the other and vice versa, then focusing is not lost.
This criteria of "closely related questions" can be reformulated as: if a possible answer for the first question in most cases will answer the second question, and a possible answer to the second question in most cases will answer the first one, then the questions are closely related and can be asked in a single question post.

All four of these individual "questions" (in quotes since they weren't asked as individual questions in the original post) are parts of a question about a single problem: "How can my current algorithm be changed to address the cases it gets tripped up on?".
The performance observation/"question" being listed here seems borderline from first glance, but it shows that they're potentially looking for a completely different approach / algorithm, rather than wanting small, incremental improvements on their existing one. It might be better to edit this "question" out, making it a footnote instead of a bullet point.
If you think that it isn't focused because it's too broad of a question:
From Is it on topic to ask for guidelines to solve a bigger problem?:

Yes, as long as the asker frames their question with enough detail on what they are trying to do so that the question doesn't:

Unavoidably require unreasonably long answers (be it due to needing too much code or explanations of too many things);
Make speculative answers unavoidable (i.e. you have to guess what the asker is trying to do);
Invite an endless list of suggestions in the answers.


The question avoids all three of these potential issues with big-picture questions:

The question asks for big picture answers (general techniques and algorithms, rather than "implement/fix this code for me") as to not "Unavoidably require unreasonably long answers"

The question is specific enough by giving the problem, the current algorithm and its (incorrect) outputs, and the intended output; as to not "Make speculative answers unavoidable".

The question restricts the possible suggested answers/technologies to C++/OpenCV only, as to not "Invite an endless list of suggestions in the answers".



"if one question in many cases implies the other and vice versa" - But this doesn't seem to be the case here. Any one of the 4 issues could exist independent from the others.  "a possible answer to the second question in most cases will answer the first one" - Also doesn't seem to be the case here. Most answers focus on one issue only - Performance, bottle-problem, or orientation. None of the answers mentions fuzziness/fuzzy at all.

""How can I fix the edge cases that my algorithm gets tripped up on?" I struggle with that - It seems to be possible to apply that logic to far too many "Needs focus" questions across all of SE. Just because someone is having "multiple issues" (edge cases, errors, whatever) doesn't automatically make them "related". If they are related, then great - Keep it open (I try to do this whenever possible), but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

@NotTheDr01ds In my opinion, the four "questions" wouldn't be related if OP was looking for specific code changes. But they're not, they're looking for a general algorithm design (as evident by the lack of code), which would have to include how those four of those points would be addressed in a single algorithm. IMO, the "needs focus" flag should be questions with multiple entirely independent problems or goals, not for questions that address multiple parts at once. Otherwise, any question that's slightly complex would "need focus"

Another thing people who seek to close questions as unfocused because they ask multiple questions should consider is, do you really want to see someone ask each of those questions as a separate question? Would that improve the presentation or the site? If all of the background information and context would need to be repeated, and all of the questions are closely-related, and it is possible to post focused answers (in this case, this is pretty much proven empirically), then it's not too broad and nothing would be served by splitting it up into multiple independent questions.

42 answers (19 of which are deleted) seems like an endless stream of answers to me. The question asks for suggestions for improvements. There doesn't seem to be and end in sight.  Some of the answers here are surprisingly good in that they would apply to many similar questions, but I would not have expected that based on how broad the original question is.

@StephenOstermiller could that just be a consequence of the score / view count, rather than the post itself? (I'd write a query but I'm failing...)

How can my current algorithm be changed to address the cases it gets tripped up on? is clearly lacking focus... so as an argument, its actually arguing that it should be closed.

@CodyGray I personally didn't VTC because of multiple questions but rather because it asked for improvements (without enough details on what that means) which is broad/opinion-based/unclear, hence, too many answers. I could also argue that it lacks MCVE, but that's a futile argument. I generally agree with your proposed "test", and even agree that asking these questions separately wouldn't necessarily be better, but I think this question fails to establish well-defined inquiries with reasonable scopes. That said, it has significant historical value and should not be deleted, imo.
